# Delphi FireDAC query execution tracing not working with connection object created by component

Tags: delphi, firedac

I created a vcl component which uses firedac to access a PostgreSQL database. This works fine, except for query tracing, which I cannot get to work.

In component constructor, I create connection object, set params etc. In the uses clause, I added FireDAC.Phys.PG and  FireDAC.Moni.Base, FireDAC.Moni.FlatFile.

Following the embarcadero docs, the TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink is created before the TFDConnection, and tracing is set to true
for both the FDTracer and the FDConnection.ConnectionIntf.

```
unit My.Database;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FireDAC.Comp.UI, FireDAC.Comp.Client, FireDAC.Phys.PG,
  FireDAC.Moni.Base, FireDAC.Moni.FlatFile;

type
  TMyDatabase = class(TComponent)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDTracer: TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink;
    FDConnection: TFDConnection;
    FConnectionString: string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function IsConnected: Boolean;
    property ConnectionString: stringread FConnectionString write FConnectionString;
    function OpenConnection: Boolean;
    function GetAsDataset(ASQL: string): TFDQuery;
  end;

implementation

uses
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
  FireDAC.VCLUI.Login, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait;

constructor TMyDatabase.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  FDTracer := TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink.Create(Self);
  FDConnection := TFDConnection.Create(Self);

  FDTracer.tracing := True;  

  with FDConnection do
  begin
    DriverName := 'PG';
    LoginPrompt := False;

    //params for PostgreSQL
    with Params do
    begin
      Add('Port=5432');
      Add('LoginTimeout=2');
      Add('Pooled=False');
      Add('OidAsBlob=No');
      Add('UnknownFormat=BYTEA');
      Add('ExtendedMetadata=True');
    end;
  end;

  FDConnection.ConnectionIntf.Tracing := True;
end;

function TMyDatabase.IsConnected: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FDConnection.Connected;
end;

function TMyDatabase.OpenConnection: Boolean;
begin
  with FDConnection do
  try
    ConnectionString := FConnectionString;

    if not Connected then
    begin
      Open;
    end;
  finally
    Result := Connected;
  end;
end;

function TMyDatabase.GetAsDataset(ASQL: string): TFDQuery;
begin
  Result := TFDQuery.Create(Self);

  with Result do
  begin
    Connection := FDConnection;
  end;

  Result.Open(ASQL);
end;
```

When I connect to a database and execute a query via GetAsDataSet, the trace file only logs the starting/stopping of the FireDac connection, but not the
execution of the query. If I put the TFDConnection and TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink components on a form or datamodule, query execution is traced as expected.

Anyone who knows how to trace the execution of a query with a connection object that is created dynamically from a component?

Best regards, Ronald

Comment: Are you sure you have fully configure `FDConnection1.ConnectionIntf` as necessary?

Comment: No, I am not sure, but I do not have reason te believe I misconfigured, as query is executed properly, and documentation states only to set Tracing property to true, which I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem in a simple FireDAC testbed of mine, by adding
a `TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink` to it and got a similar result, i.e. the trace file
contained entries saying that it had been started and stopped, but nothing in between.

Looking at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.MoniLayerClients_Sample
I seemed to be missing a small but vital step, namely to set the `MonitorBy` parameter of
my FDConnection to 'FlatFile', to match the TFDMoniFlatFileClientLink

So, just before opening the connection in my code, I added the first line below

```
  FDConnection1.Params.MonitorBy := mbFlatFile;
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;
```

and the trace then ran fine.

Partial trace extract

```
  --- new start of FireDAC Trace ---
  4361928750001 19:48:07.092 -=#!!! FireDAC Tracer started !!!#=-
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           TFDPhysMSSQLConnecti  . CreateConnection [ConnectionDef=""]
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           TFDPhysMSSQLConnecti  . CreateTransaction [ConnectionDef=""]
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           FDConnection1        >> Open [ConnectionDef=""]
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                >> Definition [Name=""]
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                     . Server=MAT430\ss2014
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                     . User_Name=sa
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                     . Password=*****
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                     . Database=MAtest
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                     . OSAuthent=No
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                     . DriverID=MSSQL
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                     . MonitorBy=FlatFile
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDConnectionDef                 $0100C390                << Definition [Name=""]
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           FDConnection1            >> FireDAC info
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           FDConnection1                 . Tool=RAD Studio 10.2
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           FDConnection1                 . FireDAC=16.0.0 (Build 88974)
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           FDConnection1                 . Platform=Windows 32 bit
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           FDConnection1                 . Defines=FireDAC_NOLOCALE_META;FireDAC_MONITOR
  4361928750001 19:48:07.094 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           FDConnection1            << FireDAC info
  4361931710001 19:48:07.390 TFDPhysMSSQLConnection           FDConnection1             . SQLDriverConnect [szConnStr="DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;UID=sa;PWD=*******;Server=MAT430\ss2014;Database=MAtest;Trusted_Connection=No;MARS_Connection=yes"]
  4361931710001 19:48:07.392 TFDPhysMSSQLDriver               MSSQL                     . ENTER SQLDriverConnectW
      HDBC                0x01044B18
      HWND                0x00000000
      WCHAR *             0x61942440 [      -3] "******\ 0"
      SWORD                       -3
      WCHAR *             0x61942440
      SWORD                       -3
      SWORD *             0x00000000
      UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

  4361935310001 19:48:07.756 TFDPhysMSSQLDriver               MSSQL                     . EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code 1 (SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
      HDBC                0x01044B18
      HWND                0x00000000
      WCHAR *             0x61942440 [      -3] "******\ 0"
      SWORD                       -3
      WCHAR *             0x61942440 <Invalid buffer length!> [-3]
      SWORD                       -3
      SWORD *             0x00000000
      UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

      DIAG [01000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'MAtest'. (5701)

      DIAG [01000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. (5703)

  4361935310001 19:48:07.758 TFDPhysMSSQLDriver               MSSQL                     . ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW
      SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
      SQLHANDLE           0x01044B18
      SQLSMALLINT                  1
      SQLWCHAR *          0x00FCB5CC
      SQLINTEGER *        0x0019F840
      SQLWCHAR *          0x0019D83A
      SQLSMALLINT               4096
      SQLSMALLINT *       0x0019F846
```

followed by the remainder of the kitchen sink.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! In fact, I did try something like that too, by adding Params.Add('MonitorBy=FlatFile'). But, as you can see in my code above, the FDConnection.ConnectionString is set just before opening to another value, overruling the Params I set during component creation:-(